# How to make the active record many to many relationship easier to develop in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, many-to-many

I have the table like this:

```
[Note]
[id]

[Note_Tag_list]
[Note_id]
[Tag_id]

[Tag]
[id]
```

Is there any active record to let me *ONLY* join these three tables?
Because every time I based on the note id to loop back the note_tag_list record, and use the note tag list record, make me feel really, really annoying.

The flow I use:

```
//loop the note the user request
//get the note by id
//use the note id to get the note tag list, and return the array of note tag list
//loop the array of note tag list and use the tag id to quest the tag
```

How do I do make this easier?

Comment: drop CodeIgniter, move to Kohana. its ORM is the way to go (AFAIR CI also has ORM, but I don't know how it works, but it's totally painless in Kohana). Just my 2 cents B)

Comment: my company have a project running on codeIgniter....it is not an easy way to drop a framework.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try [datamapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/) :)

Comment: well, sometime you can't use all the lib you want.

Comment: I think the easiest way is using ORM. It is built to solve problems related to relationship combine. Even Phil include ORM in his latest FuelPHP framework. Maybe someone knows the answer

Comment: because I have some running application using active records, well, just sad.

Comment: FYI, luckily you can run datamapper and CI active records on the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but anyways i will answer it for anyone who faces the same problem in future.

you need to use a JOIN query to connect multiple tables using primary and foreign keys relation.

**Code to get all records**

```
$q = $this->db
             ->select()
             ->from('Note AS n')
             ->join('Note_Tag_list AS n_t_l', 'n_t_l.Note_id = n.id', 'left')
             ->join('Tag AS t', 't.id = n_t_l.Tag_id', 'left')
             ->get();
```

**Code to get only specific records (by using WHERE clause)**

```
$where = array(
    'n.id' => **provide note id here**
);    

$q = $this->db
            ->select()
            ->from('Note AS n')
            ->join('Note_Tag_list AS n_t_l', 'n_t_l.Note_id = n.id', 'left')
            ->join('Tag AS t', 't.id = n_t_l.Tag_id', 'left')
            ->where($where)
            ->get();
```

For more information read the codeigniter's docs.
[Codeigniter Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)